# To change SSRS RDS connection strings using a script

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is there a way by which I can temporarily change the connection string in the RDS file to point to a new database and do this for all the RDLs in a SSRS environment using a script(can be Powershell, Batch anything). If it is possible, can someone please give me an example script that I can run in a testing environment.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. If you have a .rds file, you can simply change the connection string in that, and all reports referring to the datasource will now change where they point. Or do you have a mix of reports using the shared datasource (.rds) and embedded datasources?

Comment: Well I'm working with SSRS for the first time so may be I'm getting this wrong, but let me give it a shot..

Comment: I have several reports  (.RDL files) which have their own .RDS files and a connection string pointing to a shared database. I want to find a method by which I can run a  script and change the connection strings of all the .rds files of all the reports (.RDLs) temporarily to point to a new database instance. Does that make sense or have I confused you further??-Umang M

Comment: If the reports all use the same database, then you should have one .rds, and then each report (.rdl) should refer to that datasource. Then it is easy to change which database is used.

Comment: Well the reports do use the same database and so there's one .rds file for the corresponding .rdl files. But then again, I have a mix of reports with different .rdl files and their own .rds files having the same connection strings and pointing to the same shared database. And so, I'm looking for a method to change the connection string of one .rds file and then replicate that method for all the remaining .rds files through a script(bash, powershell, perl).

Answer (score 4):

The usual setup is to minimize the number of Data Source files. Multiple reports can use one shared Data Source connection. Then when you need to change the database, you only need to edit the data source connection in one place.